# models/formalism for optimization algorithms?

Tags: optimization

In Wolpert's "No free lunch theorems for optimization", he uses the following formalism for an optimization algorithm:
Let $X$ be a finite space of which an element has to be chosen, and let $Y$ be a finite space. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a cost function, where a higher value in $Y$ denotes a higher cost. An optimization algorithm is a mapping $a:(X\times Y)^*\to X$. i.e. an algorithm chooses an $x\in X$, then observes $f(x)$, and adds this to its list of observations, and based on the set of previous observations chooses another $x\in X$, etc.

We could have picked a different formallism for optimization algorithms, since this formalism is restrictive: it assumes that (1) the algorithm has query-access to $f$ but (2) no other type of information.

My question is not so much about this particular formalism of optimziation algorithms. My question is: **I'm interested in a list of different models that formalize the intuitive notion of optimization algorithm. i.e. what are all the different ways of formalizing it, in a more general, or simply a different way than Wolpert does here?** (I'd like as many different formalisms as possible). Is there a resource for this?

Comment: In approximation algorithms and operations research, the usual formalism is: there is a domain $X$ and a function $f\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$, and the goal is to compute or approximate $\max_{x \in X} f(x)$ or $\min_{x \in X} f(x)$. But this is a rather different type of theoretical computer science than what you're after. It's true that sometimes $f$ is given explicitly and sometimes using some sort of oracle access.

Comment: "But this is a rather different type of theoretical computer science than what you're after." How so? wouldn't it be more accurate to say that what you just gave is the general problem, whereas the formalism used by Wolpert is a formalism describing a class of methods to achieve this approximation of $min_{x\in X}f(x)$?

Comment: I think Wolpert belongs to the Theory B crowd, whereas people working on approximation algorithms are in the Theory A community, and OR are their own community.

Comment: A list of all the ways of formalizing the optimization problem seems too broad to me.  There are many optimization methods, which vary in what information is used (some use only query-access to $f$, others also rely on ability to compute its gradient, others on second derivatives, others on the structure of $f$, etc.).  I suggest reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization to get a start at an overview.